# Having problems with setInterval on longer duration

Tags: javascript, node.js

`setInterval` under node.js seems not to work for delay values of 30 and more minutes. I don't know what's the problem. Reducing delay passed to `setInterval`  in example below to just 60 seconds (by removing one `* 60`) makes it repeat correctly.

Can anyone point out any mistakes in my code?

I tried using https://www.npmjs.com/package/repeat but I had the same problem for 30 and 60 minutes intervals.

Here's a code sample:

```
function destroy() {
    console.log('Destroy');
    console.log('----------------------------------------------------------------------'); 

};

function post() {

    console.log('Post');
    console.log('----------------------------------------------------------------------'); 

    setTimeout(destroy, 1000 * 60 * 30);
};


setTimeout(destroy, null);
setTimeout(post, 1000);
setInterval(post, 1000 * 60 * 60);
```

Comment: What is it that you expect that to do? Note that each call to `destroy()` will start up a new interval timer; eventually there'll be a whole lot of them. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Removed some lines from the code to make it more clear, I want to create id in a database and then destroy it. At first will check if it exist in database and if exist destroys it then creates it every 60min and destroy it after 30min of creation

Comment: Could that be because 15 mins is way too long and the request simply times out?

Comment: Is it possible that the tab is being unloaded due to inactivity? Safari and Chrome are doing this now, and Firefox probably will follow suit soon. [Here](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/tab-discarding-and-reloading) is a reference for how Chrome decides which tabs to unload, in order of most- to least-targeted.

Comment: I'm using a raspberry pi with node on it and putty

Comment: To be honest before I had the functions as - var destroy = function(){}; instead of - function destroy() {};

Comment: Maximum value for `delay` is `2,147,483,647`, so it should work in your case. What version of node are you using?

Comment: node v0.12.6 for raspberry pi

Comment: just updated to v4.2.1 will try now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code for a long interval.  It uses timeouts of 60 seconds to check long intervals.  This should work in place of setInterval.  You could create a page that displays longInterval.items with their last run times.

```
function longInterval(fn, ms) {
  var id = longInterval.counter++;
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var item = {ms: ms, fn: fn, last: now};
  longInterval.items[id] = item;
  return id;
}

longInterval.items = {};
longInterval.counter = 0;

longInterval.run = function() {
  var items = longInterval.items;
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  for (var k in items) {
    var item = items[k];
    if (now - item.last >= item.ms) {
      item.last = now;
      item.fn();
    }
  }

  longInterval.timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    longInterval.run();
  }, 1000 * 60);
};

longInterval.clear = function(id) {
  if (longInterval.items[id]) {
    delete longInterval.items[id]
  }
};
longInterval.run();
```

usage:

```
var myInterval = longInterval(function() {
  console.log(new Date().getTime());
}, 1000 * 60);
```